# How to run a "Saved Pricing Search" using SuiteTalk?

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to run a Saved Pricing Search:
[image]

My first attempt:
[image]

My second attempt:
[image]

Both code samples get the same result:
[image]

The error message is wrong - my saved search has an internal ID of 248. My guess is that I'm using the wrong class for the search.

The problem is that I can't work out what the type of "Saved Pricing Search" is. Does anyone know it?

And where could I find the type of "Saved Pricing Search" myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response from NetSuite support:

Thank you for contacting NetSuite Customer Support. At this time, the feature you are requesting is not available within the NetSuite line of application services. We do have an Enhancement Request logged for this feature request and it has been updated with your account information and comments. Our Product Management team periodically reviews these Enhancement Requests and perhaps this will be available in a future release.

Enhancement # - 189713

Summary: WebServices > Expose Pricing search/saved search in Suitetalk